# Using C++ DLL (pointer method) in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ DLL file, I need to use it's function from C#. C++ file have a method called "Status" in ServiceState. C++ code for that block is given below.

```
STDMETHODIMP ServiceState::Status(/*[out]*/VARIANT *Primary,VARIANT *Secondary ) 
{
if(primary()) 
     Primary->boolVal = TRUE;
else
     Secondary->boolVal = FALSE;

return true;

}
```

I compiled the C++ project and got the **Status.dll** output. 
I initialized in C# code as follow.

```
 [DllImport(@"c:\Status.dll")]
 public static extern void ServiceState.Status(IntPtr Primary,IntPtr Secondary);
```

1) Whether the Initialization is correct?

2) As the method have pointers in C++, what C# data type have to be passed to that method & how? Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use C++ code in C#, you have to wrap them in C first. Then call them in C#.VARIANT? Are you using COM? COM has a totally different calling method[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Ya, I am using COM. Whether I have to wrap using C or C#?

Comment: Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx). For registered COM Servers, it could be referenced directly through "Add Reference"(e.g. Word, Excel) in VS. COM Servers are having IDLs, so you don't need to wrap anything in the C++ Dlls.

Comment: Make CLI wrappers, best way to control the flow from C# to C++. Unless you're sure you know COM perfectly (STA, MTA, registry issues)...

Comment: @YochaiTimmer thanks for your suggestion. I am reading tutorials on writing CLI wrapper.

Comment: @iamsleepy, thanks for the links. Will update the progress